# Update only a table when doing a listing with spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

On my page I have the form with the inputs for registration, and below a table that will be updated in same page. In my case my control saves, and then calls the listing, but this is made disappear the input data and the success message generated in the save method.

Save Method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView salvar(@Validated Cliente cliente, Errors errors,
                            RedirectAttributes attributes) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        clienteService.salvar(cliente);
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Cliente salvo com sucesso!!!");
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        //
    }
    return pesquisar("");
}
```

list method:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView pesquisar(@ModelAttribute("filtroPesquisa") String nomeCliente) {
    // se o nome for vazio vai retornarTodos
    List<Cliente> todosClientes = clienteService.pesquisar(nomeCliente);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("tela-cliente");
    mv.addObject("cliente", new Cliente());
    mv.addObject("clientesTabela", todosClientes);
    return mv;
}
```

Problem:
Notice that in my method list I instantiate the Client object referring to the form, and then define the list in the table. That way I always lose what was typed without an entry, and a success message does not appear. I think it's important, but I still do not understand this SpringMVC Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you want to do but as far as I understood you want to persist form values after saving data (idk why would you do that).

You have to pass filled form here

```
mv.addObject("cliente", cliente);
```

insteed of creating new one with

```
mv.addObject("cliente", new Cliente());
```

as this makes your form data disapear.

Comment: a message of success should disappear following this flow?